# Why specifically does a binary search, in all cases, run in O(log n) time, but not Θ(log n) time?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, binary-search

I understand that in the particular scenario of the best case of the binary search, the running time graph (a constant line) cannot be bounded below by any multiple of the log function (since log approaches infinity as n approaches infinity), which makes Θ(log n) inapplicable to the description of the best case, and thus it would be wrong to say Θ(log n) describes the runtime growth of *all cases* of binary search.

Is my reasoning correct?

If so, does this mean that there is always an implicit set of cases we are describing when using bigO/theta/omega notation? For instance, if someone says an algorithm runs in O(nˆ2) time, do they implicitly mean the algorithm runs in O(nˆ2) in either all cases (best, worst, and average), a subset of the cases (e.g. worst and average, but not best), or a particular case? In other words, does this mean there is no "general" bigO/theta/omega description for an algorithm, only for specific cases of algorithms (where it only sometimes may happen that all cases might be described the same)?

Comment: The nice thing with big-O notation, as opposed to big-theta, is that it expresses an upper bound on the complexity, meaning we can use it to say e.g. that an algorithm is fast without having to care about trivial or "lucky" cases and so on. If you say an algorithm runs in O(n^2), it typically means worst-case, so the bound will apply for every case. If not, you tend to specify that it's e.g. the average case only, such as often done for quicksort.

Comment: @Berthur But the fact that it applies to every case does not mean it’s the best descriptor for all cases, correct? For instance, binary search in the best case is more precisely described as running in O(1), although O(log n) technically isn’t wrong.

Comment: Well correct, but the usefulness derives from it being an upper bound. When you say binary search runs in O(logn) time, you are expressing how insanely fast it is in general, for every case. The fact that for specific inputs, it actually runs in O(1) ⊆ O(logn) is in general not interesting when conveying this information. But to answer your question, yes it does make it more complicated to use big-theta for this reason :) And this is why you typically see big-O used in the context of explaining how fast an algorithm is.

Comment: I made an attempt at compiling this into an answer, while actually trying to also answer your question. Let me know if I understood what you're asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you are correct in your reasoning. Binary search is **not** *Θ(log n)* for **every** case.

The following statements would be correct:

- It's *O(log n)* for every case.
- It's *Θ(log n)* in the worst case.
- It's *Θ(log n)* on average.

However (and this is a matter of interpretation), I might also forgive someone for saying:

- It's *Θ(log n)*.

since often, average or worst-case is assumed. But like you say, it is not true for every case, since for specific inputs, binary search can run in *O(1)*.

The nice thing with big-O notation, as opposed to big-Θ, is that it expresses an upper bound on the complexity, meaning we can use it to say e.g. that an algorithm is fast without having to care about trivial or "lucky" cases and so on. If you say an algorithm runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>), it typically means worst-case, because then the bound will apply for every case. If not, you tend to specify that it's e.g. average case only, such as often done for quicksort. This is why you usually see big-O used instead of big-Θ when listing algorithm complexities, e.g. on the Wikipedia page for binary search.

Comment: So then by convention, when we look at a runtime vs input size graph, are we looking at a graph that depicts the worst case? For example, when I look up on Google the runtime vs input size graph for the binary search algorithm, all the results depict a log curve. So is it true that this graph doesn't represent all cases, since the graph representing the best case would be a constant? I.e. for any input size N the runtime will be constant, so the curve won't resemble that log curve in the worst-case graph.

Comment: @PhilippCrosman I will be careful to say what is convention in the research community, but often you have to look at context. If you discuss the run-time complexity of an algorithm then yes it is more common to discuss average or worst-time, because those are the ones you want to compare to other algorithms. Yes those curves you saw for binary search were clearly not for the best-case scenario as you say yourself, because those special cases where the result is found in constant time do not represent reality in practice and are not interesting if you are trying to compare search algorithms.

Comment: @PhilippCrosman But again, if you want to be correct, just use the big-O notation, it inherently avoids this problem :) In the end, remember that these are just classes of functions. As an author, it is your job to make it clear what the functions you discuss actually represent.